# Task не запускает метод

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему в этом коде на выходе пустой экран.

```
class a
{
    static void Meth(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x + y);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Task t = new Task(() => Meth(5, 4));
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

Что особенно меня удивило, что через пошаговую отладку, компилятор вообще не заходит в метод Meth. Почему ?

Comment: вы точно уверены, что экран пуст? Или что запускаете именно этот код, а не какой-то другой? У меня этот код отрабатывает нормально, на экран выводится  9, как и ожидалось.  Еще отмечу, что у вас метод Main завершается сразу, тут же закрывая консоль, то есть увидеть  результат сложно физически

Comment: И правда, запустил 5 раз из них 3 выводит 9, а 2 пусто. Видать дело в том, что выход из метода Main раньше происходит. Но тогда почему в пошаговой отладке, компилятор даже не заходит в метод Meth. Теперь запустил раз 10 и все время пусто

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дело вот в чём. `t.Start` запускает `Task` на текущем `TaskScheduler`'е. Поскольку вы запускаете из не-UI-потока, у вас в нём работает `TaskScheduler` по умолчанию — тот, который выполняет `Task` в thread pool'е.

Затем, что происходит сразу после запуска задания? `Main` завершается, и программа умирает, не успев выполнить задание. Задание уходит в thread pool, но программа успевает завершиться до начала выполнения задания.

Потоки thread pool'а не приостанавливают завершение программы, если функция `Main` завершается, то при этом завершается вся программа.

Попробуйте `t.Wait()` после `t.Start()`.

Answer (score 5):

Этот код не успевает выполниться, так как программа завершает работу.

Попробуй так:

```
class Program
{
    static void Meth(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x + y);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Task task = new Task(() => Meth(5, 4));
        task.Start();
        task.Wait();

        //Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Иногда задачу (скорее задачу `ContinueWith`) хорошо выполнить в том же потоке, что и пользовательский интерфейс.

```
class Program
{
    static void Meth(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x + y);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

        Task.Factory
            .StartNew(
                () => Meth(5, 4)
                ,CancellationToken.None
                ,TaskCreationOptions.None
                ,TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
                );

        //Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Когда я делал так в WPF, то `SetSynchronizationContext` устанавливать не надо было.